# What is a slot number in Trove?

Tags: trove

What is a slot number in Trove? I was trying to delete the house I had built by saying `/clearcornerstone` but then it said it needs a slot number?

What is that?

Comment: I mean delete lol

Answer (score 0):

Basically a slot number is the place in which your cornerstone is on the list of your multiple cornerstones.

Multiple cornerstones is a new feature added by trion to trove. It means that if you want to delete a house built you have to specify which slot it is in.

If you only have 1 cornerstone, it will look something like this: /clearcornerstone 1

Alternatively you can press f1 and click on the cornerstones option to open the menu. This will let you buy/create multiple cornerstones and rename them.

Hope this helps

Source: [Trion Worlds Website](http://www.trionworlds.com/trove/en/2016/01/05/trove-unboxed-multiple-cornerstones/)